# Writing Files on iOS using Capacitor Filesystem

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm trying to store a txt file persistently on the device using the [Filesystem Plugin](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/filesystem/) of Capacitor. It works fine on Android but not on iOS.

I've tried it in an existing project as well as creating a new ionic project. I'm running the app in the Simulator on an iPhone X

This code does not work in either project.

```
import { Plugins, FilesystemDirectory, FilesystemEncoding } from '@capacitor/core';

const { Filesystem } = Plugins;

fileWrite() {
  try {
    Filesystem.writeFile({
      path: 'file.txt',
      data: "This is a test",
      directory: FilesystemDirectory.Documents,
      encoding: FilesystemEncoding.UTF8
    })
  } catch(e) {
    console.error('Unable to write file', e);
  }
}
```

Debug Console output:

```
To Native ->  Filesystem writeFile 53469622
ERROR MESSAGE:  {"errorMessage":"The file “file.txt” doesn’t exist.","message":"The file “file.txt” doesn’t exist."}
```

Are the any additional requirements/configuration to be fulfilled to store files on iOS? Am I missing something? (This is the first time working on Mac / iOS)

P.S.: I'm also trying the cordova-file-plugin, but it does not work either.

Comment: I have tested your code and it's working fine

Comment: Hi. I ran into the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Brandejs I think the main issue was, that I tried to write into a folder that didn't exist. Android creates the folder, iOS fails. Another issue cloud be the FilesystemDirectory you are using.